# Question about Weyl’s character formula of Lie algebra

Tags: representation-theory, lie-algebras

Let $\rho=\frac{1}{2} \sum_{\alpha \in \Delta_{+}} \alpha$,

$R=\prod_{\alpha \in \Delta_{+}}\left(1-e^{-\alpha}\right)$,

$P_{+}=\left\{\lambda \in \mathfrak{h}^{*} \mid \lambda\left(h_{i}\right) \in \mathbb{Z}_{+} \text {for all } i=1, \ldots r\right\}.$

For $\Lambda \in P_{+}$, let

$D(\Lambda)=\left\{\Lambda-\sum k_{i} \alpha_{i}: k_{i} \in \mathbb{Z}_{+}\right\}$ 
$B(\Lambda)=\{\lambda \in D(\Lambda):(\Lambda+\rho, \Lambda+\rho)=(\lambda+\rho, \lambda+\rho)\}.$

In the proof of Weyl's character formula : For $\Lambda \in P_{+}$, we have
$$
e^{\rho} R \operatorname{ch} L(\Lambda)=\sum_{w \in W}(\operatorname{det} w) e^{w(\Lambda+\rho)}.
$$
Suppose we already know $$
e^{\rho} R \operatorname{ch} L(\Lambda)=\sum_{\lambda \in B(\lambda)} a_{\lambda} e^{\rho+\lambda}, \text { where } a_{\Lambda}=1, a_{\lambda} \in \mathbb{Z},
$$
and $e^{\rho} R \operatorname{ch} L(\Lambda)$ is $W$-anti-invariant (i.e. multiplied by the determinant).

Then we have $$e^{\rho} R \operatorname{ch} L(\Lambda)=\sum_{w \in W}(\operatorname{det} w) e^{w(\Lambda+\rho)}+\sum_{\lambda \in B(\Lambda) \backslash\{\Lambda\}, \lambda+\rho \in P_{+}} a_{\lambda} \sum_{w \in W}(\operatorname{det} w) e^{w(\lambda+\rho)}$$

My question is:

(1)Why does  $\sum_{w \in W}$  occur? What I did is let $w \in W$ act on the equation and multiply both sides by $(\operatorname{det} w)$, but $\sum_{w \in W}$ doesn't appear.

(2)Why $\lambda+\rho \in P_{+}$ on the right hand side?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: $\lambda+\rho \in P_{+}$, so $\lambda+\rho \in $ fundamental weyl chamber, and $\sum_{w \in W}$  generate all $\lambda+\rho$.